# UWP NavigationView control doesn't support the documented PanePosition element

Tags: xaml, user-interface, uwp, uwp-xaml

According to the [Navigation view documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview), the NavigationView UI control should have a PanePosition element, but the following code gives the following error:

```
<NavigationView PanePosition="Top"/>
```

> Unknown member 'PanePosition' on element 'NavigationView'

I've tried using the latest preview release of the `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` and `Windows.UI.Xaml` NuGet packages with the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PanePosition="Top" appeared In the following Windows 10 SDK Preview Build Redstone 5